# OpenFire + Converse.js Anonymous Login is false, Authentication Fails

Tags: openfire, converse.js

I have installed OpenFire and Apache in windows, and created two users us1 & us2 in OpenFire. I have disabled Anonymous Login in OpenFire. Users able to login from Pidgin(XMAPP Client). Now Im trying to login from Converse.js, getting wired response in UI.

Here is Converse initialization

```js
    require(['converse'], function (converse) {
        converse.initialize({
            allow_otr: true,
            auto_list_rooms: false,
            auto_subscribe: false,
            bosh_service_url: 'http://localhost/httpbind/', // Please use this connection manager only for testing purposes
            hide_muc_server: false,
            i18n: locales['en'], // Refer to ./locale/locales.js to see which locales are supported
            play_sounds: true,
            prebind: false,
            show_controlbox_by_default: true,
            roster_groups: true
        });
    });
```

When I click login I see two requests going to server

```html
<body rid='3144306786' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' to='us1' xml:lang='en' wait='60' hold='1' content='text/xml; charset=utf-8' ver='1.6' xmpp:version='1.0' xmlns:xmpp='urn:xmpp:xbosh'/>
```

and Response is

```html
<body xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" from="pgi-satishb" authid="655df560" sid="655df560" secure="true" requests="2" inactivity="30" polling="5" wait="60" hold="1" ack="3144306786" maxpause="300" ver="1.6"><stream:features><mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><mechanism>DIGEST-MD5</mechanism><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism><mechanism>CRAM-MD5</mechanism></mechanisms><compression xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/compress"><method>zlib</method></compression><bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind"/><session xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-session"/></stream:features></body>
```

And Next request is

```html
<body rid='3144306787' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' sid='655df560' type='terminate'/>
```

Response

```html
<body xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind" type="terminate"></body>
```

Now I'm in dark, don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing Helped so downloaded latest code from https://github.com/jcbrand/converse.js/archive/master.zip 
which solved the problem